# Scala how to instantiate new Option[java.sql.Date] type

Tags: string, scala, date, scala-option

I have var date_of_birth2 : Option[java.sql.Date] = None.

Later I have to fill date_of_birth2 by string.

```
 String date = "01/01/1990"
 var formate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date)
 var aDate = new java.sql.Date(formate.getTime());
```

But aDate is just the type of java.sql.Date. How can I assign?

var mdate_of_birth2 : Option[java.sql.Date] =  date  // date is just String type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of explicitly using a `Some`, as suggested by @hezamu, you could use the `apply` method on the `Option` companion like so:

```
val maybeADate:Option[Date] = Option(aDate)
```

In this case, in the off chance that `aDate` was null, then your `Option` would be a `None` instead of `Some(null)` which would be undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `parse` method will throw an exception if there is a formatting error, you might also consider using `Try`, to squash failures to `None`.

```
val aDate = Try(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date))
    .map(d => new java.sql.Date(d.getTime()))
    .toOption
```

If you *do* want it to throw an exception, then I would go with @cmbaxter's answer using `Option.apply`.

Answer (score 1):

You wrap it in `Some`:

```
var mdate_of_birth2: Option[java.sql.Date] = Some(aDate)
```

You should see if you can refactor your code to make it a `val`, though.